How to test a link in vitest imported from tanstack router
In the parent component the link is being rendered
import { Link } from '@tanstack/react-router';

export default function Parent() {
  return (
    <div><Link to='/'>Test</Link></div>
  )
}

in the test case i'm mocking the link
vi.mock('@tanstack/react-router', () => {
    return {
        default: () => <a href="/">Test</a>
    }
});

But i'm getting the following error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'buildLocation')
Tried below case as well, only the not found route is loaded and not the link.
test('Should render tanstack router link', () => {
    const rootRoute = createRootRoute();
    const indexRoute = createRoute({
        getParentRoute: () => rootRoute,
        path: '/',
        component: () => <Link to="/">Hello</Link>,
    });

    const router = createRouter({
        routeTree: rootRoute.addChildren([indexRoute]),
        basepath: '/',
    });

    render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
});

My questions are

How to mock tanstack router links
How to test a link mocking the tanstack router setup, I have simplified here with a link actually the component is bigger with lot of links.

